# Запуск нескольких ботов одновременно

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Решил уместить функционал нескольких ботов в один файл, так как уже много их в папке. Но проблема что из всех ботов запускается только первый в

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            bot1.polling(non_stop=True, interval=0, timeout=60)
            bot2.polling(non_stop=True, interval=0, timeout=60)
            bot3.polling(non_stop=True, interval=0, timeout=60)
        except Exception as e:
            time.sleep(2)
```

Запускается только bot1, функционал других не работает, как это исправить и сделать запуск сразу нескольких ботов, или это невозможно на telebot и надо переходить на aiogram?
Пробовал реализацию через threading:

```
def bot1polling():
    bot1.polling(non_stop=True, interval=0)
def bot2polling():
    bot2.polling(non_stop=True, interval=0)
def bot2polling():
    bot3.polling(non_stop=True, interval=0)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            bot1poll = Thread(target=bot1polling, daemon=True)
            bot1poll.start()  
            bot2poll = Thread(target=bot2polling, daemon=True)
            bot2poll.start()  
            bot3poll = Thread(target=bot3polling, daemon=True)
            bot3poll.start()  
        except Exception as e:
            time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: случаем не threading?

Comment: Я пытался через threading, но у telebot есть такая штука что он может вырубиться через пару часов из-за timeout error. Хотя может я неправильно threading реализую

Comment: А как вы пытались через `threading`? Можете в вопрос поместить?

Comment: Добавил в вопрос мою реализацию через threading

Comment: может не `non_stop`, а `none_stop`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так:

В начале файла:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
```

В конце файла (перезапишите код `if __name__ == '__main__'` этим кодом):

```py
def start_bot1():
    bot1.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0, timeout=60)

def start_bot2():
    bot2.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0, timeout=60)

def start_bot3():
    bot3.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0, timeout=60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            bot_thread1 = Process(target=start_bot1, args=())
            bot_thread2 = Process(target=start_bot2, args=())
            bot_thread3 = Process(target=start_bot3, args=())

            bot_thread1.start()
            bot_thread2.start()
            bot_thread3.start()

            bot_thread1.join()
            bot_thread2.join()
            bot_thread3.join()
        except Exception as e:
            time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Проблема в том что боты сходят с ума, polling каждый раз перезапускается и ответ на 1 команду может копироваться трижды.

Comment: А вы мой код пробовали?

Comment: Это и есть последствия Вашего кода. Вот такое выходит в консоли:
A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 409. Description: Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running (якобы бот несколько раз запущен)

Comment: Это ошибка в вашем коде. Проверьте, чтобы были разные токены у всех ботов.

Comment: ну так у вас один токен наверное

Comment: Токены разные. Перепроверил

Comment: Ну не верится... Не может такого быть.

Comment: Сам сижу в шоке

bot1 = telebot.TeleBot(token='6055823742')

bot2 = telebot.TeleBot(token='6121080393')

bot3 = telebot.TeleBot(token='6251298903')

Comment: Ну сейчас проверю у себя, как это работает..

Comment: Из-за цикла while он запускает ботов каждую секунду, поэтому происходят такие вот конфликты. Но без него боты попросту будут ложиться спать из-за нестабильности телеграмма

Comment: @robo.copp попробуйте так, я обновил ответ

Comment: Ну и спустя эту минуту история повторяется

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146298/discussion-between-robo-copp-and-peter-kolosov).

Answer (score 0):

Создаем список из ботов в переменной `bots` и потом передаем этот список в `start_polling`. Это код для aiogram v3

```
async def create_bots():
    tokens = await base.fetch("SELECT token FROM tb_bots WHERE enable = True")
    bots = {}

    for i, data in enumerate(tokens, start=1):
        token = data.get('token')
        bot_name = f"bot{i}"
        bots[bot_name] = Bot(token=token, parse_mode="HTML")

    return bots

bots = []
bots_dict = await create_bots()
for bot in bots_dict.values():
    bots.append(bot)
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)

dp.startup.register(startup)
dp.shutdown.register(shutdown)

await dp.start_polling(*bots, polling_timeout=30000, close_bot_session=True)
```